# Laravel - Composer unable to find the service provider class

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I have been creating a [Laravel package](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/laravel-censor) (a Middleware). My folder structure looks like the following:

```
laravel-censor/
    config/
        sensor.php
    src/
        CensorMiddleware.php
        LaravelCensorServiceProvider.php
    composer.json
```

And the content of `composer.json` is:

```
{
    "name": "kamranahmedse/laravel-censor",
    ...
    ...
    "require": {
        "php" : ">=5.4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.1.11"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "KamranAhmed\\LaravelCensor\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I have released it to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/kamranahmedse/laravel-censor) and can be found through [github](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/laravel-censor). Now after installing

```
composer require kamranahmedse/laravel-censor
```

When I add the package's service provider to `providers` array in `config/app.php`

```
KamranAhmed\LaravelCensor\LaravelCensorServiceProvider::class
```

And run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

### The problem

It is unable to find the service provider class and throws a class not found exception. Can any body please point out what am I doing wrong here? Why is composer not able to autoload this class?

I have been looking into this for over an hour now and unable to figure out the problem that why composer isn't autoloading this class. Also, I have checked and the namespaces and class names are all correct:

```
# LaravelCensorServiceProvider.php
namespace KamranAhmed\LaravelCensor;
...
class LaravelCensorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{ ... }
```

### Solution

It turned out that composer had some cache. Running `php artisan clear-compiled` after clearing the composer cache `composer clear` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could install your package and execute `php artisan vendor:publish` without any issues, have you tried `composer dumpautoload`? and `php artisan clear-compiled`?