# L5 service providers not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, composer-php, service-provider

**Problem**

Love L5. But last 24h been a nightmare. None of my 3rd party service providers (SP) are loading. I did a clean install of L5 and tried adding the SPs but still not working.

The SPs install as they should in the `vendor` folder when running `composer update`. But when running the L5 I get the error message `Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found`

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "*",
    "intervention/image": "*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "*",
    "davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-laravel5",
    "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.1.*",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "1.5.5",
    "league/csv": "*"
},
```

**app.config**

*providers*

```
    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * 3rd Party Service Providers...
     */
    Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider::class
```

*aliases*

```
    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'Debugbar'  => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
    'Image'     => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
    'PushNotification' => Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\Facades\PushNotification::class,
    'LaravelLocalization'   => Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::class
```

**Things I tried**

[Laravel 5.2 Service provider not booting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502249/laravel-5-2-service-provider-not-booting)

`php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize`

[Laravel - Composer unable to find the service provider class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687435/laravel-composer-unable-to-find-the-service-provider-class)

`composer clear`

I've also scorched the internet but come up dry.. :( https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-package-serviceprovider-cant-be-found)

**Ideas?**

Any ideas how to overcome greatly appreciated. Cannot run the app now and lost a day of work.. :/

**UPDATE**

The `autoload_files.php` in `vendor/composer` does NOT contain some of the frameworks. `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` is part of it (does not get loaded) but for instance `Mcamara\LaravelLocalization` is NOT part of the autoload_files.

But the `Mcamara\LaravelLocalization` is part of the `autoload_static.php` under `$prefixesPsr0` - if that helps?

*autoload_files.php (in /vendor/composer/)*

```
return array(
    '1d1b89d124cc9cb8219922c9d5569199' => $vendorDir . '/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php',
    '0e6d7bf4a5811bfa5cf40c5ccd6fae6a' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php',
    '667aeda72477189d0494fecd327c3641' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php',
    'bd9634f2d41831496de0d3dfe4c94881' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php56/bootstrap.php',
    '2c102faa651ef8ea5874edb585946bce' => $vendorDir . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php',
    'e7223560d890eab89cda23685e711e2c' => $vendorDir . '/psy/psysh/src/Psy/functions.php',
    '5255c38a0faeba867671b61dfda6d864' => $vendorDir . '/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php',
    'f0906e6318348a765ffb6eb24e0d0938' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php',
    '58571171fd5812e6e447dce228f52f4d' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php',
    'a0edc8309cc5e1d60e3047b5df6b7052' => $vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php',
    'f18cc91337d49233e5754e93f3ed9ec3' => $vendorDir . '/laravelcollective/html/src/helpers.php',
    '4a1f389d6ce373bda9e57857d3b61c84' => $vendorDir . '/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/helpers.php',
```

);

**SOLUTION**

A THIRD clean install of L5 where I add in the SPs ONE by ONE seems to work. Just happy to be back on track. **Cannot thank everyone enough - big shout out to @MikeBarwick** who provided good guidance throughout - THANKS! :)

Comment: A clean install and `composer update`? That definitely isn't a good combination. Composer update merely installs the libraries in your composer.lock file. Did you try running `composer install`?

Comment: if You take out LaravelLocalization and keep the other 3, does it work or move to another class? Which one?

Comment: Are you able to see commands list if you run just `php artisan`? Try with `composer update --no-scripts` in case, then `composer update` again.

Comment: RahulGovind: Tried. No joy :/
MarcoAurélioDeleu: Tried. Moves to all other classes (if I only put in one that one fails)
phaberest: Will reinstall and see if works

Comment: @phaberest php artisan works fine. Composer update also.

Gut feeling tells me it is a cache issue. Clean install. Ran `composer install` which requested me to run `composer update`. Did that, packages installs successfully. Added service providers to config. Issue still persists - the SPs do not load :/

Comment: Try deleting `Vendor/Composer` folder and `composer.lock` file AND then run `composer update`

Comment: @MikeBarwick Deleting the Vendor/Composer folder leads to the following error when running composer update "Warning: require_once(vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. `composer update` should regenerate that lock file. Question - you're running composer update from your project root, right? Also - can you post/link your composer.json file?

Comment: @MikeBarwick Your right. Was running composer update from www root, not folder root (what happens when you try to cram this in over lunch :)). But deleting the vendor/composer folder stalls composer update from finishing (see above)

Comment: Try just removing composer.lock and running composer update (in correct project root)

Comment: @MikeBarwick still no joy. Let me update my question with the autload_files in the composer folder - might be helpful

Comment: Go through each of the files in vendor/composer folder and remove all code related to the problematic package (that's throwing the error, etc.), then remove composer.lock, and then composer update.

Comment: When you installed the package...are you sure you were in the project root?

Comment: @MikeBarwick Yes. When I now deleted the information relating to the LaravelLocalization class and run composer update it still does not work. However, if I try to uninstall the package (deleting it from composer.json and running composer update) I now get " I get "Package Mcmara/laravel-localization-1.1.3.0 seems not properly installed". I really appreciate your help btw. Feels awful to be stuck for 30h on this :/

Comment: @MikeBarwick got it to work via a 3rd clean install. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! My guess was, your were running composer installs/commands outside of project. ;) Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: If someone else stumbles on the same issue I think the problem was that I copied the composer.json from my existing project over to the newly created L5 installation. When I instead copied the relevant fields within the composer.json and pasted in the newly created and ran composer update things ran smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo - but still no joy :/

Answer (score 0):

It's because your are missing class in providers file

```php
$this->app->register(\L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider::class);
```

Paste it under register
hope so it will start working.